# Como saber cuantos pixeles se ha movido un raton

Tags: python, python-3.x

quiero crear un código que al hacer `click` guarde la posicion actual y empiece a registrar cuantos pixeles ha recorrido, pero no se me ocurre nada, hice algo diferente con `pyautogui.position()` jugando con las variables `x,y` pero no fue un exito, no funciono como esperar.

como podría hacerlo?

Comment: Lo que te interesa contar es la trayectoria completa hasta el siguiente click, o la distancia entre el click inicial y el final?

Comment: al hacer click, se declare una variable en 0 y que al mover el mouse vaya contando cuantos pixeles ha recorrido, estoy muy enredado intentando cosas, si me pudieses ayudar estaría agradecido! @ErickG.Islas-Osuna

Comment: Puedes mostrar lo que intentaste con `pyautogui.position()` y qué resultado obtuviste?  Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info en cómo mejorar la pregunta. Un saludo

Comment: @lois6b lo que intente fue un fracaso, guarde la posicion en x,y y luego cree un if que si x pasara de 500 ejecutara una accion, pero no resulto, ni se acerco a lo que queria lograr

Comment: pyautogui.drag(30, 0, 2, button='right'), como esa funcion registra que ha llegado a los 30 pixeles, quiero algo similar en mi codigo @lois6b, un saludo y gracias por responder!

Comment: Desconozco las funciones de Python, pero la cantidad de pixels la puedes calcular mediante la [distancia entre dos puntos](http://1234matematicas.blogspot.com/2013/01/distancia-entre-dos-puntos.html,) tendrías que ir calculando y acumulando hasta que alcances el valor deseado.

Comment: @Fly me dice que la pagina no existe, si pero yo no se el color al pixel al que yo voy a mover el mouse, entonces como compararia? porque el teorema de pitagoras se usa comparando dos pixeles, soy un poco novato

Comment: @Fly creo que me has ilumando, cierto! con el teorema de pitagoras creo que puedo lograrlo, gracias

Comment: Perdón!! el enlace tiene una coma de mas: http://1234matematicas.blogspot.com/2013/01/distancia-entre-dos-puntos.html

Comment: estuve probando tantas cosas que me ofusque y la respuesta siempre la tuve en mis estudios, muchas gracias @Fly por mencionar la distancia entre dos puntos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Otra opción a Pyautogui es *Win32api*. aquí te dejo dos códigos para que los combines según necesites.
El primero. imprime la posición cada vez que cambia la posición del ratón:

```
import win32api

temp_x, temp_y = win32api.GetCursorPos() #initial position
while True:
    x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    if (x != temp_x or y != temp_y):
        print("("+str(x)+","+str(y)+")")
    temp_x = x
    temp_y = y
```

Y el segundo código imprime la posición actual cuando haces clic izquierdo:

```
import win32api, win32con, time

estado_clic = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)  # obtener evento clic izquierdo inicial
#Si el botón está presionado da 0 o 1. Si se suelta da -127 o -128

temp_x, temp_y = win32api.GetCursorPos() # posicion inicial
while True:
    estado_actual = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
    if estado_actual != estado_clic:  # si cambia de estado
        estado_clic = estado_actual
        # print(estado_actual)
        if estado_actual < 0:
            print('Botón clic presionado')
            x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
            if (x != temp_x or y != temp_y):
                print("("+str(x)+","+str(y)+")")
                temp_x = x
                temp_y = y   
        else:
            print('Botón clic liberado')
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

Para la distancia entre dos posiciones puedes usar el *Teorema de Pitágoras* para dos puntos(Suponiendo los puntos (x1,y1)  y (x2,y2)), la distancia sería:

```
distancia = sqrt( (x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2 )
```